# Set a timer to know how long the unknown face was on the screen in face recognition using opencv in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, opencv, face-recognition

I'm learning face recognition using opencv in python and wondering If I can set a timer to know if the unknown face gets detected for more than 5 seconds than I will call some `function()`. So I used start time and end time inorder to get the difference of 5 but it's not working properly. Any clue to make this code working ?

```
def gen(camera1):
    startTime = time.time()
    while True:
        label, frame = camera1.get_frame()
        if label=="unknown":
            endTime = time.time()
            if (endTime - startTime > 5):
                print("Inside If condition Longer than 5 seconds")
                function()
        else:
            yield b'--frame\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'
            yield frame
            yield b'\r\n\r\n'
            yield label
```

Comment: What does “not working properly” mean? Be specific, and if there isa Python error include the _full_ error message with trackback into your uestion.

Comment: Apologize for not being specific. It means that the startTime it records when I initiate the cam and records endTime as soon as it detects unknown face because the time when it starts and till when it detects unknown face would be greater than 5 but what I actually want is to wait and count for 5 seconds when it detects an unknown face and if the condition returns true than it will execute the `function()`